# How to build locally installed R package?

Tags: r, package

I installed a development version of an R package directly from R Forge via `install.packages("pckgname", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`. I would now like to also install the same version on a computer that has no internet access. How can I compile a source (.tar.gz) version of the package I installed from R-Forge to then install on this computer?

Comment: The source is downloaded when you do `install.packages`, and you can set the download directory with the argument `destdir`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent That worked, thanks! I wasn't aware of this option in the `install.packages` function